# How to use 'exactly' in a question?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-order

I have a sentence:

> Which tasks should I perform?

How do I add *exactly* to this question?

> 1. Which exactly tasks should I perform?
> 2. Which tasks should I perform exactly?

Neither of the above sentences seems right to me. Is *exactly* the right word? How to ask the question to find out what exactly I'm supposed to do?

It's really hard to find any information about the usage of exactly, so I hope I you can help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Exactly* is an adverb, so you can not use it to modify a noun (*tasks*). That means your first sentence is not grammatical.

You have two options:

> 1. Exactly which tasks should I perform?
> 2. Which tasks should I perform exactly?

As @StoneyB points out, the second option can be ambiguous.

In the first sentence, *exactly* clearly modifies *which*, but in the second one, it seems to modify *perform*. If it modifies *perform*, you're asking which tasks should be performed with great(er) accuracy.
The second sentence can, however, also be read as if *exactly* modifies *which*, just like in the first one. In that case, the adverb just moved to the end of the sentence, more or less as an afterthought. One might add a comma in that case:

> Which tasks should I perform, exactly?

In most cases, I *think* the second sentence would be interpreted as meaning the same as the first.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful because the placement of "exactly" can make a huge difference.

> Exactly which tasks should I perform?

You are asking for the specific individual tasks, out of many more possibilities, that you should perform.

> Which tasks should I perform, exactly?

Same as above, but *the common and inflection during speech are **very, very** important* because...

> Which tasks should I perform exactly?

You are asking which of the already defined tasks should you perform exactly as instructed/defined as opposed to "close enough".

Comment: Honestly all three of your examples are semantically equivalent.